# wp_insert_term does not insert description.

Tags: description, terms

I'm using this code. I cannot figure out what the heck is wrong with it?

```
$args = array(  
    'description',"My Desc",
    'slug' => "My Slug",
    'parent' => 0   
);  
$result = wp_insert_term("Term1", "category", $args);
```

The result is that term is added, term_taxonomy is added. Slug is added. But the darn description is skipped.

```
wp_terms:

term_id name            slug            term_group
1       Uncategorized   uncategorized   0
2       Blogroll        blogroll        0
3       Term1           my-slug         0

wp_term_taxonomy:

TT_id  T_id tax        description  parent  count
1      1    category                0           0
2      2    link_category           0           0
3      3    category                0           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem the other day, due to a completely different typo ;)

```
$args = array(  
    'description' =>"My Desc",
    'slug' => "My Slug",
    'parent' => 0   
);  
$result = wp_insert_term("Term1", "category", $args);
```

Note the corrected 'description' element in the $args array.